# Forms Authentication Error in WCF

Tags: wcf, authorization

We are connecting to a WCF web service which has Anonomous Access turned off, Windows Authentication turned on.  The web.config file has a local user account for allow users and deny users="?".

I can download and generate the service proxy fine (being prompted for creds), however from my windows form project (even when passing in the credentials), I get the following error:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException was unhandled
  Message="The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm=\"SEIPART001\"'."

Message="The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."
```

Here is my sample code:

```
ip.eIPCShoppingCartWSSoapClient client = new iParts.ip.eIPCShoppingCartWSSoapClient();
System.Net.NetworkCredential creds = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");

client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = creds;
iParts.ip.OrderListItem[] listItem = client.GetOrderList("1234"); //throws exception here
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your service is asking for *basic* authentication; not windows integrated authentication.

In that case, I think you need to specify the credentials on the client proxy using in the ClientCredentials.UserName property and not ClientCredentials.Windows.

Answer (score 0):

No change.  The virtual directory is asking for Windows Auth and passing in a local user.  It works fine in the browser but the service keeps erroring out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should switch to transport security.
Lookin the security section of your configuration.